# C++: Initialize an array of pointers to objects with different types

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Is there a syntax in C++ to initialize an array of pointers to objects with different types without extra assignments? I tried to provide a complete example below.

```
#include "stdio.h"

class Base {
    public:
        Base(int cnt=1) : _cnt(cnt) {}
        virtual void print() { printf("?\n"); }
    protected:      
        int _cnt;       
};      

class A : public Base {     
    public:     
        A(int val, int cnt=1) : _val(val), Base(cnt) {}
        void print() override { for (int i=0; i<_cnt; i++) printf("A(%d)\n", _val);  }
    private:
        int _val;
};

class B : public Base {
    public:
        B(const char* val, int cnt=1) : _val(val), Base(cnt) {}
        void print() override { for (int i=0; i<_cnt; i++) printf("B(\"%s\")\n", _val);  }
    private:
        const char* _val;
};

//  *** I would like to combine the following statements ***
A a = { 42, 2 };
B b = { "hi there", 3 };

Base* test[] = { &a, &b };

int main() {
    for (auto *x : test) { x->print(); }
}
```

When I try

```
Base* test2[] = {
    &A(42, 2), 
    &B("hi there", 3),
};
```

I get errors for *taking address of temporary*. The code needs to run code on a small embedded system, so I try to avoid dynamic allocation.

Hope this is not a FAQ ...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not without dynamic allocation

Comment: The error message says exactly what's wrong. Use `new A(42,2)`. Better use smart pointers

Comment: How big is the set of types? Is it open or closed?

Comment: @StoryTeller: There are about 10 different types of objects.

Comment: And can there be more added at any time? Or is the set of types closed?

Comment: @StoryTeller: No, it is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example:

```
Base* test2[] = {
    &A(42, 2), 
    &B("hi there", 3),
};
```

Both `A` and `B` are being instantiated within the scope of the array initializer. They are temporary to this scope, and this is why the compiler will not allow you to store them in the array.

You should use smart pointers to dynamically allocate your objects, since accessing a stack variable outside of it's scope is unsafe.

A good example of a smart pointer is a `shared_ptr`:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: Thank you for the hint! However, I forgot to mention that the code needs to run on a small embedded system with very limited resources.

Comment: @Matthias In that case change the array to store `Base` (not `Base *`), and you can instantiate them the way you have done in your example, without the `&`, of course.

Comment: You mean like this @snoopy?

`Base test2[] = {
 A(42, 2), 
 B("hi there", 3),
};` 

However, then I get the followin error:

`unable to deduce 'auto*' from '* __for_begin' for (auto *x : test2) {`

Comment: @Matthias That compile error has nothing to do with the original problem, in fact your original problem seems solved.  Simply remove the * in the statement `auto *x : test`, and you should compile fine.  This is because you are no longer storing pointers.

Comment: You are right @snoopy - this is a different thing. If I change the statement to `for (auto x : test2) { x.print(); }` it compiles fine.

However, the output is ? ? now.

Comment: Won't that array declaration slice the derived classes? and cause odd things to happen.

Comment: @Matthias it is outputting "? ?" now becuase you are calling the `Base` class member function for `print`.  If you want to call the `A` or `B` member print function, then you have to use `dynamic_cast` to cast the `Base` down to either `A` or `B`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: @TomTanner I am unsure what "slice the derived classes" means. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The array is of base classes, and hence the array elements are all base classes. So if a derived class is of different size to the base class, you won't get all of the derived class in the array. Just the base part of it. See (e.g.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Answer (score 1):

Your post mentions you want value semantics, which means no dynamic allocation. In the comments you mentioned that your set of types is closed. So you can go for closed set polymorhpism with [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html).

```
using common_t = boost::variant<A, B>;

common_t arr[] = {
    A(42, 2), 
    B("hi there", 3),
};
```

The nice thing is that the types need not have a common base anymore. They only need to respect the same interface (have `print`). You essentially replace dynamic with static polymorphism. Now a generic lambda can be used to access any member

```
for(auto &obj : arr)
  boost::apply_visitor([](auto& o) {
    o.print();
  }, obj);
```

Comment: Just had a look at boost::variant and it looks great! However, Boost seems not to be available for the target system :-(
I would like to +1 your answer, but my reputation is not high enough yet.

Comment: @Matthias - Well, that's unfortunate. Boost is terrific in my opinion. And I do believe this is the best solution to your problem in-general, if platform considerations didn't apply. And don't worry about upvotes, I'm just glad I could help somehow.